# toolbarItems disappear after dismissing keyboard of which the inputAccessoryView was set to the toolbarItems

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I've added some items to toolbarItems and they are showing properly when the view is first loaded. After the below function is called, just before the keyboard is shown on the screen, the items disappear from the toolbar

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    let keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolBar.sizeToFit()
    keyboardToolBar.items = toolbarItems
    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar
    return true
}
```

After dismissing the keyboard, the toolbar is still there but the items are not showing, if I print the count of toolbarItems, I can see that the items are still there. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: you will need to add items to toolbar items. and make sure to provide your generated array

Answer (score 0):

check like this

```
func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
    let keyboardToolBar = UIToolbar()
    keyboardToolBar.backgroundColor = .cyan
    keyboardToolBar.sizeToFit()
    let btn1 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneBtnAction))
    keyboardToolBar.items = [btn1]
    textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolBar
    return true
}

@objc func doneBtnAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    aTextView.resignFirstResponder()
}
```